# SWFMovie not found error

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I made a lot of researches about how to add ActionScript code to a swf file and i finally found the ming extension for PHP, under Windows i have installed it, activated and restart Wamp but i'm still getting the error :

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'SWFMovie' not found in C:\wamp\www\site\emu\title.php on line 2
```

This is title.php :

```
<?php
$m = new SWFMovie();
?>
```

(I know it's stupid but it's just for testing).
Under Linux it works perfectly !
Does anyone know what's going on ?

Comment: where is the class `SWFMovie` declared, and where is it in relation to `title.php`?

Comment: The SWFMovie class is in the extension ming_php as i said, here is a screenshot : http://oi60.tinypic.com/zjf4zp.jpg

Comment: sorry, didn't pick up on that - the extension is configured properly? are you able to run one of the examples from this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.swfmovie.php?

Comment: Actually, i haven't touch the configuration, just downloaded the dll and placed it to the extensions folder of PHP in Wamp, and no i'm not able to run any of the examples :'( Thanks a lot divillysausages for your answers :)